# What is wrong with this js code, Returning variable from function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a project where i post "thumbsup" and "like" click via AJAX/POST on a PHP Script. This returns after processing, depending if the user is logged in or not an error array (with json_encode). 0 means its all ok, 1 means the user was not logged in. The submit function i have written does not return the error variable after redefinig it on each loop. When i do console.log(error) on each loop it does return 1, but when i check it on click function it returns false. I have the following 2 functions:

I cant seem to understand what i am doing wrong.

```
function submit(tip,varid){
    var error = false;
    $.post( "/rwfr.php", { name: ""+tip+"", id: ""+varid+"" })
     .done(function( data ) { 
        var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $(results).each(function(key, value) {
            error = value['error'];
            return false;
        })
    });
  return error;
}

$(".fa-thumbs-up").click(function(){
    var idObj = $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-id");
    var act = submit('thumbsup',idObj);
    if(act == "1"){
        console.log(act);
        alert("You must log in before you can rate this video!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Remove `return false;` in `each` loop.

Comment: See also [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: You know that the submit function returns long before the .done function gets called right?

Answer (score -2):

**Though it is down voted, I've kept this answer as someone with similar problem may find this simple and helpful.**

The reason it's returning `false` in your case is that, by the time you get the response from `submit()`, your next line i.e. `if(act=="1")` is being run, which will of course return false since you've initialized `error` with vallue `false`.

What you can change in your function is that, you may just move your snippet that checks the error in response received inside a callback function which must be called within `.done()` of your post request.

See below,

```
// your submit function
function submit(tip, varid, callback){
    var response = $.post("post.php", { name: ""+tip+"", id: ""+varid+""});
    response.done(function(data){
        callback(JSON.parse(data), tip);
    });
}

// your callback function
function callbackFunction(response, action_type){
    // handle your prompts here based on your action_type i.e. thumbs up, down, favourite, etc.
    console.log(response);
    if(response.hasOwnProperty("error") && response["error"]=="1"){
        console.log("you need to login to do this!");
    }
}

// and pass the callback function to your submit function
var act = submit('thumbsup',idObj, callbackFunction);
```

Comment: From what i know return false does break the each loop. I did tried it without return false, same result.

Comment: `return false` inside of jQuery's `.each` will stop the iteration. This would not be the case in the native `.forEach` or in lodash or underscore. This is a horrible design decision on their part in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, this works without the each loop. but still what is wrong with my code? Is there any way to make it work like i wannted to in first place. I cannot use the errors output inside the submit function because i will use this function for more actions ( thumbs up, thumbs down, watch later, add to favorite, report) so every click action should have its own message.

Comment: okay. you may check the edit part of the answer now